# Нахождение всех вариантов составления массива из последовательностей с общим числом повторяющихся элементов k

Tags: алгоритм, комбинаторика

Предположим, мы используем только 1 и 0 при составлении массива длины N. Нужно найти количество способов разместить k единиц так, чтобы они входили как последовательности с длиной большей двух.
Пример подходящих последовательностей для N = 6, k = 3.
001011 - не подходит, так как присутствует изолированная единица.
000111 - подходит

Comment: И даже ничего не попытались сделать, хотя бы втупую посчитать? Жаль, задача ведь интересная.

Answer (score 1):

Пусть *f(n, k)* искомое число. Тогда

*f(n, k) = f(n-1, k) + f(n-3, k-2) + (n-4, k-3) + f(n-5, k-4) + ... + f(n-(n-3), k-(n-4)) + f(n-(n-2), k-(n-3)) + f(n-(n-1), k-(n-2)) + f(n-n, k-(n-1)) + f(n-n, k-n)*.

Формулы выводится из рассмотрения того как могут быть устроены старшие цифры последовательности. Рядом с шаблоном строки приведено количество строк соответствующих шаблону:

> ```
> шаблон         число вариантов шаблона
>
> 0XXXXX...XX  - f(n-1    , k      )
> 110XXXX..XX  - f(n-3    , k-2    )
> 1110XXX..XX  - f(n-4    , k-3    )
> 11110XX..XX  - f(n-5    , k-4    )
> ...
> 11...110XXX  - f(n-(n-3), k-(n-4))
> 11...1110XX  - f(n-(n-2), k-(n-3))
> 11...11110X  - f(n-(n-1), k-(n-2))
> 11...111110  - f(n-n    , k-(n-1))
> 11...111111  - f(n-n    , k-n    )
> ```

Чтобы формула и таблица хорошо работали нужно доопределить *f* для маленьких *k* и *n*:

*f(n, 0) = 1*, *f(n, k<0) = 0*, *f(n<0, k) = 0*.

Answer (score 0):

Сначала нужно создать массив из нулей длиной N. Затем в цикле разместить k единиц с помощью счетчика. На каждой итерации цикла увеличиваем счетчик, пока он не станет равен N - 1, чтобы убедиться, что последовательность из единиц имеет длину больше 2